# FactoryGirl with local variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

I'm trying to create a time_slot at some random time in the future:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :time_slot do
    week_num = (rand(10) +1)
    day_num = (1+rand(30))
    hour_num = (1+rand(12))
    future_date = week_num.weeks.from_now
    my_time = Date.local(future_date.year,future_date.month,day_num, hour_num)
    sold_out false
    fitness_camp
    start_time {my_time}
    end_time {my_time + 8.weeks}
```

But this results in a `undefined method + for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Static`

I know this would work in one huge line, but there has to be a clean way to do this. It is confusing to have local variables mixed with attributes, so is the best practice to put this function somewhere else and generate the Factory by overriding the default date?

Thanks,

tim

Comment: One thing that stands out is the use of the equal sign. I don't believe you need those and they are probably screwing up the syntax. Also, should `(rand(10) + 1)` be `{ rand(10) + 1 }`?

Comment: the equal signs are there for local variables . . . they are not model properties

Comment: ah, ok. good to know. I didn't realize you could do that...

Comment: i say i'm doing it all wrong -- create a method to get this done in the spec helper and just pass the dates to the Factory

Comment: you can do that to a limited degree -- but running methods in the static assignment is not a good idea (i think)

Answer (score 3):

Use `Random.rand()` instead of just `rand()`

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :time_slot do
     week_num = (Random.rand(10) +1)
     day_num = (1+Random.rand(30))
     hour_num = (1+Random.rand(12))
     future_date = week_num.weeks.from_now
     my_time = Date.local(future_date.year,future_date.month,day_num, hour_num)
     sold_out false
     fitness_camp
     start_time {my_time}
     end_time {my_time + 8.weeks}
```